# Realm Swift : List of objects not working

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

I try to connect Realm to my recipe application in Swift. I have a problem about the ingredients : when I run my app, I have this error coming

```
There must be a primary key property named '_id' on a synchronized Realm but none was found for type 'recipe_ingredients'
```

I assume it is because I typed my ingredient object as a Realm Object and it wants a primary key. I tried to add one, but then it says

```
Primary Key for class 'recipe_ingredients' has been added.
```

Here is my model file :

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class recipe: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId?
    @Persisted var name: String?
    @Persisted var category: String?
    @Persisted var image: String?
    @Persisted var note: Double?
    @Persisted var likes: Int?
    @Persisted var ingredients: List<recipe_ingredients>
    @Persisted var steps: List<recipe_steps>
    @Persisted var time: String?
    @Persisted var units: Int?
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}

class recipe_ingredients: Object{
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId?
    @Persisted var name: String?
    @Persisted var quantity: String?
}

class recipe_steps: Object{
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId?
    @Persisted var step_description: String?
    @Persisted var step: Int?
}
```

And here is the Realm Schema

```
{
  "title": "recipe",
  "properties": {
    "__v": {
      "bsonType": "int"
    },
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "category": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "image": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "ingredients": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "quantity": {
            "bsonType": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "likes": {
      "bsonType": "int"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "note": {
      "bsonType": "double"
    },
    "steps": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "properties": {
          "description": {
            "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "step": {
            "bsonType": "int"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "time": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "units": {
      "bsonType": "int"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You may want to check out these two links: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Persisted.html and https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. Both seem to suggest that your ObjectId property should not be an optional

Comment: Hello Sir,
you can refer to the below link for the primary key setup.
https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-primary-keys-tutorial/

Comment: @Rob Hi, I tried to make ObjectId not optional but then I have an error saying this : "Property 'recipe._id' has been made required."

Comment: Once a property is added to an existing object (an additive change), changing it would be a destructive change and you can't do that directly without deleting the objects and starting again or performing a manual migration. If this is a sync'd Realm each object will need a primary key and a good way to do that is `@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId` which will ensure the object, when instantiated, receives a unique primary key as required by Realm. If this is sync'd you're going to need primary keys anyway so, using the above code, you don't need to make them optional.